# grunt is not working using maven plugin

Tags: node.js, maven, gruntjs, maven-plugin

Hi i am working with grunt and Maven .

used plugin to start Grunt

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>${basedir}/scripts/gruntFiles</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <executable>grunt</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

this plugin is not working to start grunt when i start maven project.

Grunt file :-

```
var proxySnippet = require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest;

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
    require('time-grunt')(grunt); 

    grunt.initConfig({
        yeoman: {
            // configurable paths
            app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
            dist: 'src/main/webapp/resources/dist'
        },
        watch: {
            compass: {
                files: ['src/main/scss/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            styles: {
                files: ['src/main/webapp/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
                tasks: ['copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: 35729
                },
                files: [
                    'src/main/webapp/resources/scripts/rrh/authoring/basket_app/directives/templates/*.html',
                    '.tmp/styles/**/*.css',
                    '{.tmp/,}src/main/webapp/resources/scripts/**/*.js',
                    'src/main/webapp/resources/images/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
                ]
            }
        },

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        // Define our source and build folders
        js_directives_path_rrh_ui: "../rrh/rrh-ui/directives",
        js_src_path_home_rrh: "../rrh",

        //output folder path
        js_output_folder_path: "../gruntOutputFiles",

        // Grunt Tasks
        concat: {
            options:{
                separator: ';',
                mangle: false,
                compress: true, linenos: false,
            },
            // used for home page internal js files
            js: {
                src: ['<%= js_src_path_home_rrh %>/common/rrh-common.js',
                      '<%= js_src_path_home_rrh %>/rrh-ui/directives/RrhUiDirectives.js'
                     ],
                dest: '<%= js_output_folder_path %>/home_app.js'
            },
        },
        uglify: {
            options:{
                mangle: false,
                compress: true, linenos: false,
                banner: '/*! <%= pkg.title || pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version + "\\n" %>'
            },
            // used for home page internal js files
            js: {
                src: '<%= concat.js.dest %>',
                dest:'<%= js_output_folder_path %>/home_app.min.js'
            },
        });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

    grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
        grunt.task.run([
            'concat',
            'uglify',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'concat',
        'uglify',
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'build'
    ]);
};
```

Please help to run it ..

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" ? Also, I am pretty sure that the <phase> configuration is not correct. It has to be one of the Maven lifecycle phase: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-core/lifecycles.html

Comment: Not only pretty sure your definition of `<phase>..</phase>` is simply wrong.

Comment: yes you are rite .. what it should be ? please make it correct

Comment: i changed it :- <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>generate-resources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>build</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <executable>grunt</executable>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) it does not look like. The exec-maven-plugin does not have a **build** goal.

Comment: Yes Grunt have and it is working for my another project.  '<execution>
                        <id>run-grunt</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an article that describes how to setup maven to work with grunt:
http://addyosmani.com/blog/making-maven-grunt/

it also includes an example setup script:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <executable>grunt</executable>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the frontend maven plugin is far and away the best plugin for this type of build/deploy process. https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin .

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>

    <!-- optional -->
    <configuration>
        <workingDirectory>src/main/frontend</workingDirectory>
    </configuration>

   <execution>
    <id>grunt build</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>grunt</goal>
    </goals>

    <!-- optional: the default phase is "generate-resources" -->
    <phase>generate-resources</phase>

    <configuration>
        <!-- optional: if not specified, it will run Grunt's default
        task (and you can remove this whole <configuration> section.) -->
        <arguments>build</arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>
</plugin>
```

One thing to be aware of it is will download node for the system it is being run on, so if you have a different OS on your build server, you'll need to make sure that is the version you have checked into version control, your local version (for me OSX) will have to be maintained local to your project.